# how to use VBA to convert from vertical data to horizontal data?

Tags: excel, vba

i have moved my data from one sheet to another via VBA. I want to use tableau to visualise the data. But it can only read the data if it is horizontal. I need the year to loop it self and then insert the data next to it as shown in below picture. I have added the code that i use to move data, in the last part if needed. I need to make this possible via VBA and not using the transpose function.

The picture is an example of what i would like it to look like.. "the result i seek"

**EDIT ADDED:**

[image: ark1 data added here]

[image: Ark2 i get the data from here]

```
    Sub MyProcedure()
a = Worksheets("ark1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox (a)

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim nøgletal As String, år As Integer
    Worksheets("Ark2").Select
    nøgletal = Range("B2")
    år = Range("C2")
    Worksheets("Ark1").Select
    Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A4").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("C1:C100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("C12:C100").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("D1:D100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("D12:D100").Value
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("E1:E100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("M12:M100").Value
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("F1:F100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("N12:N100").Value
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("G1:G100").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("O12:O100").Value
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A1:A16").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark2").Range("A12:A16").Value
    If Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A4").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Ark1").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = nøgletal
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = år
    Worksheets("Ark2").Select
    Worksheets("Ark2").Range("B2", "B16").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Aske, what is the problem? Error message... wrong results...

Comment: look at `transpose` like `range("s1:u1").value=application.transpose(range("a1:a3").value)` something along those lines.

Comment: @AngelM. The picture is an example of what i would like it to look like.. "the result i seek". it moves the data just fine, but i dont know how to make it horizontal.

Comment: Which sheet is shown in your picture? Where is the data C1:C100 which were copied from Ark2!C12:C100? (range size doesn't match!)

Comment: @Variatus it is because there will be way more data. i copy from Ark2 to Ark1

Comment: Nothing can be programmed like "there will be way more data". Try to say something like, "Data from Ark2!C2:C[End] should go to Ark1!A2>horizontal." Problem is you don't disclose where the data in your picture's L:M come from. It seems that they come from Ark1, but the implied description of Ark1 taken from your code doesn't match the picture of what must be presumed to be a partial Ark1. Try to post a picture of Ark1 with some 10 rows of data.

Comment: @Variatus ahh sorry i just added the sheet where the data is added from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your image with the coloured cells and what you seek.  This does what you show

```
    Sub x()

Dim lngDataColumns As Long
Dim lngDataRows As Long

lngDataColumns = 3
lngDataRows = 4

For t = 1 To lngDataRows

Range("l2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Range("e1:g1").Value)

Range("M2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Range("e1:g1").Offset(t).Value)

Next t

End Sub
```

Comment: ' it seems like the "M2" part is deleting my row "M" in my data sheet. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a new version in VBA that will do what you expect. The flow to know when the system stops searching is based in the contents, so, while the column on the left for the yearly contents be blank, the system will continue searching but when found a value (e.g. SCIENCE) it will stop searching. 
This first part is an example of how can you call the function to specify the source and destination Sheets and also the values in integers where your range can be found:

```
Private Sub TestingCall()
    Call SpecialTranspose("Ark2", "Ark1", 1, 5)
End Sub

Private Sub SpecialTranspose(strSRCSheet As String, strDSTSheet As String, lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long)
    Dim iRow, iCol As Long
    Dim dstRow, dstCol As Long

    dstRow = 1
    dstCol = 1

    iRow = lngRow + 1
    While Len(Sheets(strSRCSheet).Cells(iRow, lngCol - 1).Value) = 0
        iCol = lngCol
        While Len(Sheets(strSRCSheet).Cells(iRow, iCol).Value) > 0
            Debug.Print iRow, iCol
            Sheets(strDSTSheet).Cells(dstRow, dstCol).Value = Sheets(strSRCSheet).Cells(lngRow, iCol).Value
            Sheets(strDSTSheet).Cells(dstRow, dstCol + 1).Value = Sheets(strSRCSheet).Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
            dstRow = dstRow + 1
            iCol = iCol + 1
        Wend
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just `transopose`???  `sheets(2).range("a1").resize(cols,rows).value=application.transpose(sheets(1).range("a1").resize(rows,cols).value` along those lines?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: If you look well, it is not exactly a transpose but a diferent case where the headers (years) need to be in the left column every time. By the way, I checked with your command and shows me "Syntax Error"